# Fetching fallback url if the first url fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function

```
  getAllSymbolsConfig = async reels => {
    const symbols = new Set();

    for (const column of reels) {
      for (const symbol of column.symbols) {
        symbols.add(symbol);
      }
    }

    const coords = {};

    for (const symbol of symbols) {
      const response = await fetch(
        `${this.props.gameDir}icons/${symbol}.json`
      );

      const json = await response.json();

      coords[symbol] =
        json.frames.find(frame => frame.filename.includes("active_0000")) ||
        json.frames.find(frame => frame.filename.includes("active")) ||
        json.frames[0];

      coords[symbol].meta = json.meta;
    }

    return coords;
  };
```

where it tries to fetch data from url **`${this.props.gameDir}icons/${symbol}.json`**

However, in some situations ${symbol} variable is not available and I need to replace it with hardcoded url icon.json:

```
${this.props.gameDir}icons/icon.json
```

How would i retry the second fallback url if the first one fails?

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Try this:

```
function fetchData(url) {
 await fetch(url).then((response) => {
  return response;
 })
}
let response = null;
response = fetchData(`${this.props.gameDir}icons/${symbol}.json`)
if (response.status == 400 ) {
 response = fetchData(hardCodedUrl)
}
if (!!response) {
 response.then((returnedResponse) => {
  // Your response to manipulate
 }).catch((error) => {
  // Your error is here!
  console.log(error)
 });
}
```

Comment: what kind of error is thrown if  first try failed. Is it 500 response code?

Comment: error is 400. But it doesn't try to fetch the url inside of catch

Comment: ok . try this. await fetch(`${this.props.gameDir}icons/${symbol}.json`).then((response) => {
    if (response.status == 400 ) {
      //call another function to fetch data from hardcoded url
    }
    return response;
})